# Sorting list with x%2==0 in sort function gives me undesired result

Tags: python

My array is

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If I do a sort on it using

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
```

I get

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I was expecting

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Why is that ?

Comment: The `==0` reverses the result.

Comment: Because `True == 1`

Comment: @buran. This question relies on stable sorting, the other wants two sorting criteria. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, fair enough, I retract my close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Klaus D. stated - "The ==0 reverses the result."

If x is odd then the key value is 0. If x is even then the key value is 1. 0 is less then 1, so the odd numbers appear first, followed by the even numbers, just as you specified.

You can either, add the `reverse` flag like the following:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x : x%2==0, reverse=True)
```

Or switch the condition like the following:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x : x%2!=0)
```

Or just use the `%` without the `==` like the following:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x : x%2)
```

Comment: How about just `x % 2`?

Comment: @KlausD. Adding it

Answer (score 5):

Your key function `lambda x : x%2==0` will yield `False` and `True`
and

```
>>> False < True
True
```

the result is what you asked for :-)
you can pass `reverse=True`
or better

```
>>> sorted([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], key=lambda x: x % 2)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: I votedUp this answer, in my opinion - showing the list after apply the lambda function on each element will clarify the explanation - `[item % 2 for item in a]` --> `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` - as an intermediate step

Comment: @YossiLevi, ty for the comment. definitely helped me

Answer (score 2):

Python `bool` is a subclass of `int` with exactly two instances, `True` and `False`. The instances are ordered, but not in the way you seem to expect, since `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

For odd numbers `x % 2 == 0` is `False`, so odd numbers are sorted first. The opposite is true for even numbers.

Two alternative ways to express the expected condition would be

```
x % 2 == 1
```

Or just

```
x % 2
```

The first is a `bool`, the second an `int`. You could explicitly turn the second into a `bool` with `bool(x % 2)` instead of comparing to `1`.

The original condition `x % 2 == 0` can be rephrased as an `int` with `1 - x % 2`.

Answer (score 1):

`==` will reverses condition. `!=` instead of `==` is working: `sorted(a, key=lambda x: x%2 != 0)`